# DTMC : Example of Irreducible Aperiodic Null Recurrent Chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Can someone give me an example of a Discrete Time Markov Chain (DTMC) which is

- Irreducible
- Aperiodic
- Null Recurrent

I know that a Simple Symmetric Random Walk on Integers is Irreducible Periodic and Null Recurrent but I am having a tough time coming up with a Markov chain which has the aforementioned properties.

Comment: The simple symmetric random walk on the integers is *null recurrent*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a random walk on the integers where the jump distribution satisfies 
$$\mathbb{P}(\xi=-1)=\mathbb{P}(\xi=0)=\mathbb{P}(\xi=1)=1/3.$$
Allowing the walk to sit still with positive probability "kills" the periodicity.

This chain is null for the same reason as the simple, symmetric random walk. If the new chain  were positive, it  would have a unique invariant probability measure $\pi$. The only non-negative solution to $\pi=\pi P$ is a constant sequence $\pi(k)\equiv c$, which cannot be a probability measure.

Comment: is this for any state?

Comment: Yes, the transition kernel satisfies $p(k,k-1)=p(k,k)=p(k,k+1)=1/3$. That is what "random walk" usually means.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland, I am sorry but I am sort of unconvinced that this is null recurrent. Can you give me a rough sketch of a proof why it is null recurrent?

Answer (score 0):

In your example take $p=q=\frac{1}{2}$

EDIT: if $p>q$, your MC is positive-recurrent; otherwise it is transient.

Comment: This is periodic (with period 2)

Comment: No it's not: if period was two, you return to the starting state w.p. 1 after two periods, which is not the case here.

Comment: If I am at zero. How many steps does it take to return to 0? Can I return in 1 or 3?

Comment: @Inquest: It might take any no. of steps, but has a non-zero probability. You are perhaps confusing a simple random walk?

Comment: @Shyam, yeah. Alex said "in your example". The example I stated was simple, maybe that's the confusion.

Comment: Alex, do you mean simple symmetric random walk or just the simple random walk on integers?

Comment: @Inquest: "Symmetric" is $p=q=0.5$. Not the presence of 0 and 1 states only.

Comment: Oops. I meant only symmetric (no simple).

Answer (score 0):

A symmetric random walk on integers (where you move left or right each with probability $p=0.5$) is null recurrent. When the probability $p\ne 0.5$, the walk becomes transient.

Comment: I don't think so: take $q>\frac{1}{2}$ and MC becomes transient

Comment: The simple symmetric RV has period of 2

Comment: @Inquest: Period? This random walk spans all integers. For period 2, you need just 0 and 1.

Comment: @Inquest: no it's not:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Periodicity

Comment: @Shyam, what's your definition of period.

Comment: @Shyam: if you start at any state $k$ with $q>p$, then try finding mean first hitting time of state $s_0$, you will get $m_{k,0}=1+m_{k,0}$, hence mean first hitting time is infinity

Comment: @Alex: My mistake: the random walk on all integers is either null recurrent or transient. It can become pos. rec. only if we restrict to $\{0,1,2\ldots\}$ and $p>q$.